# XPath - select value

Tags: xpath

Good Day
I would like to attain the VALUE of the national_id.
I am struggling as the value is in a separate element and not to sure how to select it ONLY.

I would like "1234567891011 (ZAF-ID)" to be returned.

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <env:Body>
      <wd:Get_Workers_Response wd:version="v32.2" xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc">
         <wd:Response_Data>
            <wd:Worker>
              <wd:Worker_Data>
              <wd:Integration_Field_Override_Data>
                     <wd:Field_Reference>
                        <wd:ID wd:type="WID">12345</wd:ID>
                        <wd:ID wd:type="Integration_Document_Field_Name" wd:parent_type="Integration_Document_Name" wd:parent_id="INT017 Field Override for Worker">passport_number</wd:ID>
                     </wd:Field_Reference>
                  </wd:Integration_Field_Override_Data>
                  <wd:Integration_Field_Override_Data>
                     <wd:Field_Reference>
                        <wd:ID wd:type="WID">67891</wd:ID>                      
                        <wd:ID wd:type="Integration_Document_Field_Name" wd:parent_type="Integration_Document_Name" wd:parent_id="INT017 Field Override for Worker">national_id</wd:ID>
                     </wd:Field_Reference>
                     <wd:Value>1234567891011 (ZAF-ID)</wd:Value>
                  </wd:Integration_Field_Override_Data>
                  <wd:Integration_Field_Override_Data>
                     <wd:Field_Reference>
                        <wd:ID wd:type="WID">111213</wd:ID>
                        <wd:ID wd:type="Integration_Document_Field_Name" wd:parent_type="Integration_Document_Name" wd:parent_id="INT017 Field Override for Worker">network_logon</wd:ID>
                     </wd:Field_Reference>
                  </wd:Integration_Field_Override_Data>
                  <wd:Integration_Field_Override_Data>
                     <wd:Field_Reference>
                        <wd:ID wd:type="WID">141516</wd:ID>
                        <wd:ID wd:type="Integration_Document_Field_Name" wd:parent_type="Integration_Document_Name" wd:parent_id="INT017 Field Override for Worker">role_size</wd:ID>
                     </wd:Field_Reference>
                     <wd:Value>M</wd:Value>
                  </wd:Integration_Field_Override_Data>
                  <wd:Integration_Field_Override_Data>
                     <wd:Field_Reference>
                        <wd:ID wd:type="WID">171819</wd:ID>
                        <wd:ID wd:type="Integration_Document_Field_Name" wd:parent_type="Integration_Document_Name" wd:parent_id="INT017 Field Override for Worker">ts_organization</wd:ID>
                     </wd:Field_Reference>
                     <wd:Value>Information Technology</wd:Value>
                  </wd:Integration_Field_Override_Data>
                  <wd:Integration_Field_Override_Data>
                     <wd:Field_Reference>
                        <wd:ID wd:type="WID">202122</wd:ID>
                        <wd:ID wd:type="Integration_Document_Field_Name" wd:parent_type="Integration_Document_Name" wd:parent_id="INT017 Field Override for Worker">mutual_branch_user</wd:ID>
                     </wd:Field_Reference>
                     <wd:Value>N</wd:Value>
                  </wd:Integration_Field_Override_Data>
                  </wd:Worker_Data>
            </wd:Worker>
         </wd:Response_Data>
      </wd:Get_Workers_Response>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Any assistance would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

this is working

```
//wd:ID[text()="national_id"]/ancestor::*/wd:Value/text()
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

To complete @Alexander Riedel's answer, two other options :

```
//wd:Value[preceding::wd:ID[1][.="national_id"]]/text()

//wd:ID[.="national_id"]/../following-sibling::wd:Value/text()
```